# elasticsearch painless array first element

Tags: elasticsearch

There are many objects of the following type:
mapping:

> ```
>   {
>     "_index": "crm",
>     "_type": "order",
>     "_id": "1",
>     "_score": 1.0,
>     "_source": {
>       "executionPercent": 50,
>       "phase": [
>         {
>           "phaseId": "1",
>           "phaseName": "phaseOne",
>           "startDateTime": "2019-11-12T18:09:51.894Z",
>           "endDateTime": "2019-11-12T21:15:43.797Z"
>         },
>         {
>           "phaseId": "2",
>           "phaseName": "phaseTwo",
>           "startDateTime": "2019-11-12T21:15:43.797Z"
>         }
>       ],
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "_index": "crm",
>     "_type": "order",
>     "_id": "2",
>     "_score": 1.0,
>     "_source": {
>       "executionPercent": 10,
>       "phase": [
>         {
>           "phaseId": "1",
>           "phaseName": "phaseOne",
>           "startDateTime": "2019-11-13T06:37:45.850Z"
>         }
>       ],
>     }
>   }
> ```

I need to search objects in which startDateTime in the "phase" array (the first element) was between dateFrom and dateTo
query:

```
 {
    "query": {
        "filter": {
            "script": {
                "params": {
                    "dateFrom": 2019-11-11
                    "dateTo": 2019-11-12
                },
                "script": "doc['startDateTime'][0].value > dateFrom && doc['startDateTime'][0].value < dateTo"
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Maybe use "lang": "painless"?
sorry for my english and code

Answer (score 0):

Range query can be used to search documents based on date fields. Below is a sample code that finds the documents that are having startDateTime between the given from and to date.

```
GET crm/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "phase.startDateTime": {
        "from": "2019-11-11",
        "to": "2019-11-12"
      }
    }
  }
}
```